# I need ideas/prior research for a persistent interator

Tags: algorithm, iteration, partitioning, audit

I need some help thinking about an algorithm.

I have a collection of documents, potentially numbering in the millions.  These documents are also indexed in MySQL.  In extreme cases, this index needs to be rebuilt.  Given the large number of documents, the reindexing needs to happen in most recent to least recent.  But more importantly, the reindexing needs to start over again at the same point after a computer reboot (or equiv).  And given that index a million documents can take a long time, new documents might be added during the reindexing.

This same collection could be mirrored to another server.  I would like to have an auditor that would make sure that all documents exist on the mirror.

In both cases users will be accessing the system, so I can't tie up to many resources.  For the first case, I would very much like to get an ETA when it would finish.

I feel these are the same problem.  But I can't get my head around how to do it efficiently and cleverly.

The brute force approach would be to have a list of the millions of documents + timestamp they were last checked/indexed.  I would then pull the "next" one out of the list, check/index it, update the timestamp when done.

This seems wasteful.

What's more, given that a document might be added to the system but the list not adequately updated, we'd have to have an auditor that would make sure all documents are in the list.  Which is the basic problem we are trying to solve.

I've seen such an auditor described in multiple situations, such as large nosql setups.  There must be description of clever ways of solving this.

Comment: Sounds like your auditor is also your indexer. You seem to expect indexing to take a long time, and to give preference to recent additions. Can you segment the job into work-packets? Is there something like a document-counter which you can exploit to find documents not part of any particular work-packet? I'm thinking you could segment by day (or week...) of document arrival, if they're timestamped.

Comment: I'm kinda thinking about 2 things at once.  Both an indexer and auditor.  The auditor makes sure the DB and FS are in sync.  Note that the FS could potentially be a remote FS (aka more likely to get out of sync).  I don't have the date of document arrival but I do have the date of document creation.  These will often differ, say when adding all previous invoices when my system is installed but also for accounting reasons (create the invoice now, but bill it next quarter).  The documents are stored in a type/YYYY-MM/DD/DOC structure.  But YYYY-MM, type, DD would be the ideal indexing order.

Answer (score 0):

I would go,as always turns out with efficiency, for a segmented index.
You probably can divide the whole DB lot into smaller DBs, index them, then index the indices themselves. And only re-index the ones who have changed.
For the new entries while re-indexing, just keep the new entries in a new, temporary DB and just merge that DB into the big DB when the re-index is finished.

You can enhance this approach recursively for the smaller segments. You would have to analyse the trade off of how many segmentation levels will give you the fastest re-index time.

Comment: So partition the problem into smaller segments, potentially prioritize some segements, and save state each time a segment is done.